# Send image as API response

Tags: java, http, playframework

I need to send images as API response.I created a response but i still cant not send the image.I am using play framework with java.

```
Http.Response response = new Http.Response();
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not really know what version of play are you using but this should work for 2.X

```
public static Result returnImage(){     
    return ok(new File("public/img/1.jpg")).as("image/jpg");  
}
```

Here you can see that **ok()** can receive a File as a parameter. To check all the options you can go to [Play Framework JavaDocs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html).

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks. the problem is it gives me file not found exception!! i  made sure the path is correct!

Comment: Glad it helps. If this was the answer please check it so its close. thnks!

Comment: thanks worked, the issue is the directory if assets was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is correct, however if image is large, I would suggest using chunks and streams:

```
public Result send() throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("some_path/test.jpeg"));
    response().setContentType("image/jpeg");
    return ok(fis);
}
```